# how to access vuejs refs if ref value has bracket character

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to access the ref of input, but still getting undefined.

// sample in template
template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" v-bind:value=meminfo.last_name name="online_membership[last_name]" ref="online_membership[last_name]" >
```

Script:

```
methods() {
   function() {
     // i would like to access the input value of this ref
     this.$refs.online_membership[last_name]
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a simpler name? Since your template only has one element, you can also use `this.$el`

Comment: Yeah, would really like to do that but I have to changed a lot in the backend side and stored records in the db.

Comment: I don't understand. The `ref` is only used by Vue and has nothing to do with your back-end. You might as well use `ref="input"`. FYI, `methods() {` should be `methods: {`

Comment: Just use bracket notation instead of dot notation and also agree with @Phil.

Comment: I have 2 functions : 1. axios post getting the values placing it into the meminfo which is v-bind. it contains the current information
2. second function, gets another axios post specific to the input field that will replace the current value of the meminfo

Comment: It's an existing system, we are replacing an old framework and replacing it with vuejs

Comment: @Phil I tried your last suggestion it works man, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change something like below:

best practice:

// sample in template template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" v-bind:value=meminfo.last_name name="online_membership[last_name]" :ref="online_membership[last_name]" >
```

Script:

```
methods() {
   function() {
     // i would like to access the input value of this ref
     this.$refs[online_membership[last_name]]
   }
}
```

but still if you want to use as a string including '[' then simply you can use below solution:

// sample in template template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" v-bind:value=meminfo.last_name name="online_membership[last_name]" ref="'online_membership[last_name]'" >
```

Script:

```
methods() {
   function() {
     // i would like to access the input value of this ref
     this.$refs['online_membership[last_name]']
   }
}
```

hope it will solve your problem

Comment: thanks man, @Phil already answered my question