# How to access in v-bind or v-model object id with bracket

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

my data has an object containing id with brackets
i would like to access it in the template to display

[image: this is my template]

this is my vue debugger
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: Did you not get this answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59403754/283366)?

Comment: already tried that approach, though it works in access $refs

{{ req_meminfo[online_membership[first_name]] }}

{{ [req_meminfo[online_membership[first_name]]] }}

Comment: yes I did get that for $refs but for placing the value inside the div like {{ with brackets}} , would like to achieve that as well. if this is not doable I'll just try to look for a workaround instead :)

Comment: Did you try using as an array notation =>  req_meminfo['online_membership[first_name]']. Note key is passed in string.

Comment: v-bind:value='req_meminfo["online_membership[first_name]"]' works, already received advised from other forum

Answer (score 0):

```
v-bind:value='req_meminfo["online_membership[first_name]"]'
```